# Express upload replaces images in folder and uploading photos somewhere else

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, backend

I am trying to implement a profile picture into my website and I am running into a problem where one image [newimg] that is uploaded has the same name as another image [oldimg] uploaded earlier, this image replaces the older image file in my folder and changes the profile picture for any user that has that older image [oldimg] to the newer one [newimg].

I followed this [guide](https://codingshiksha.com/javascript/how-to-upload-image-to-mysql-database-in-node-js-express-using-fileupload-and-display-it-using-ejs-full-tutorial/) and managed to upload photos to a folder where the problem I stated above happens. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/user/:uid/updatepicture', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.files);
if(!req.files) {
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
}

var file = req.files.uploaded_image;
var img_name=file.name; 

if(file.mimetype == "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype == "image/png"||file.mimetype == "image/gif" ) {
    file.mv('public/images/uploaded_images/' + file.name, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("userId: " + req.session.user_id);
        console.log("img_name: " + img_name);
        let stmt = 'update users set profile_img=\'' + img_name + '\' where userId = ' + req.session.user_id + ";";
        connection.query(stmt, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            res.redirect('/user/:uid');
        })
    })
}})
```

I am also using mysql to store user data and express-fileupload. I'd like to know how to solve the duplicate image name problem happening in the folder or find an alternative to uploading profile pictures for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience using express but I faced a similar problem in laravel and came up with this.
Every time you need to upload an image, randomly append some numbers (say 4 digits) before an image name while retaining the original extension.

Looks something like this:

```
   $image = $request->file('image');
   $new_image_name = rand(). '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $image->move(public_path("images"), $new_image_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create unique new name with rand before move file.